# Add Check box in second column in CListCtrl in MFC

Tags: checkbox, mfc, clistctrl

In my MFC application, im adding `CListCtrl` in my View class using `OnCreate()` function. I have 10 columns and 8 rows in that table. I want to include check box in second column . 
My code is

```
int CTrendView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT l)
{

m_ctLstCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT ,listRect, this, IDC_TRENDLISTCTRL);

    m_ctLstCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(m_ctLstCtrl.GetExtendedStyle()  | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES| LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT| LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE );

    m_ctLstCtrl.SetBkColor(RGB(255,255,255));
    m_ctLstCtrl.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,0));
    m_ctLstCtrl.SetTextBkColor(RGB(255,255,255));

    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(0,_T(""),LVCFMT_LEFT,10);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(1,_T("Visible"),LVCFMT_LEFT,50);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(2,_T("Status"),LVCFMT_LEFT,50);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(3,_T("Color"),LVCFMT_LEFT,50);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(4,_T("Object1"),LVCFMT_RIGHT,100);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(5,_T("Object2"),LVCFMT_RIGHT,100);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(6,_T("Desc"),LVCFMT_RIGHT,100);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(7,_T("Value"),LVCFMT_LEFT,100);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(8,_T("Low"),LVCFMT_LEFT,100);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(9,_T("High"),LVCFMT_LEFT,100);
}
```

Im using below function to add green color in third column and fourth column.

```
void CTrendView::OnCustomdrawMyList ( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult )
{

NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR );

   *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

   switch(pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
   {
   case CDDS_PREPAINT:
      *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
      break;

   case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
      *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
      break;

   case (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM):  
       {
         if(pLVCD->iSubItem == 2 )                    
               pLVCD->clrTextBk  = RGB(0, 255, 0);  
         else
            pLVCD->clrTextBk  = RGB(255, 255, 255);
       }

       for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
       {
           if(pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec == i && pLVCD->iSubItem == 3) 
                pLVCD->clrTextBk  = PenSelect[i];              
       }    
      break;
   }

}
```

For adding dynamic values for other columns im using one Fucntion getting called from `OnDraw()`.

```
void DrawData(CDC *pDC,int iTagPos,CListCtrl &TagListctrl,CRect rect,int pType,float pScaleLow,float pScaleHigh, int TimeCursorPos,int pFlag,CString stime)
{

    int index;   
    CString sPV, sType;     
    sType = ".SV";
        if (TrendTempSV[TimeCursorPos] != -999999)
        {               
        sPV.Format ("%3.2f",TrendTempSV[TimeCursorPos]);            
        }
        else
          sPV.Format ("%s","**.** ");       


        CString sScaleLow,sScaleHigh,indexno;
        sScaleLow.Format ("%4.1f",pScaleLow);
        sScaleHigh.Format ("%4.1f", pScaleHigh);
        indexno.Format("%d",iTagPos+1);
        TagListctrl.SetRedraw( FALSE );
        TagListctrl.DeleteItem(iTagPos);
        index = TagListctrl.InsertItem(iTagPos,indexno);

        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,4,"Object");
        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,5,sName);
        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,6,sDesc);
        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,7,sPV);
        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,8,sScaleLow);
        TagListctrl.SetItemText(iTagPos,9,sScaleHigh);
        TagListctrl.SetRedraw( TRUE );  

}
```

I want check box under 'Visible' column. FOr that, i include | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES in SetExtendedStyle.

```
m_ctLstCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(m_ctLstCtrl.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES|
                                         LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT|  LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE );
```

Im facing below problem by doing this. Checkbox appears in first column with index number. The ListCtrl start to flicker,headers are not visible,only when i click somwhere in listctrl each column header et appears one by one and the sixe of the listctrl also not same as previous. How can i avoid this?

Comment: _"For adding dynamic values for other columns im using one Fucntion getting called from OnDraw()"_ -- You are breaking the API contract here because you are using a callback function that is intended only for drawing, to modify data of the control. This causes the control to be invalidated, triggering another redraw, which calls your function again, and so on.

Comment: Yes..actually i want to display current value in that control .Already in tht code they used CDC for drawing table and placed this values.Instead i want to have List control instead of drawing table like structure. And also the values getting changed every some micro seconds.In CView im adding CLIstCtrl, so i have update values continously..either i have to use OnTImer() or this.??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [`XListCtrl`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1796/%2FArticles%2F1796%2FXListCtrl-A-custom-draw-list-control-with-subitem). It features checkbox columns at arbitrary positions as well as text formatting of cell content (color).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [CListCtrlExt (or CListViewExt)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213901/%2FArticles%2F213901%2FListCtrlEx-control), which are not custom draw !! that is mean you can have OS style intact and you can put on every column, any kind of control, including check box button ...