# Add checkbox in second column in CLIstctrl in mfc

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I want to add checkbox in second column and all check boxes need to checked in default. By adding LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES in Extended Style, the check box adding to first column. 
I create ListCtrl using OnCreate();

```
m_ctLstCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT ,listRect, this, IDC_TRENDLISTCTRL);

    m_ctLstCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(m_ctLstCtrl.GetExtendedStyle() |LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES|   LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT|  LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE );
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(0,_T(""),LVCFMT_RIGHT,20);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(1,_T("Visible"),LVCFMT_LEFT,50);
    m_ctLstCtrl.InsertColumn(2,_T("Status"),LVCFMT_LEFT,50);


Edit: In another question, the answer is mentioning updating CListCtrl . But i need only moving first column check box to second column.Is that possible to do that? I tried CImageList to get Check box bitmap in second column. But as im new to using CLIstCtrl. i cannot find the solution.
```

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074381/add-check-box-in-second-column-in-clistctrl-in-mfc ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Check box in second column in CListCtrl in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074381/add-check-box-in-second-column-in-clistctrl-in-mfc)